# Print value of javascript in php

Tags: php, javascript, printing

I need to code something like that to print value of javascript in php

```
<?php

$url = ( Value of <script>document.write(top.location.href);</script> );

echo ''.$url.'';

?>
```

---

**Update:**
I need this to break frames, block proxy websites and bots so $_SERVER not useful

Please can anyone help me ?

Thank you

Comment: Why don't use php direct?

echo "http://" .$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

Comment: @semsem I need this to break frames, block proxy websites and bots so $_SERVER not useful

Comment: @COLDTOLD I don't know how  to use ajax

Comment: You can't access one frame from another from within PHP.  You also can't do it from Javascript if the frames are from different domains.

Comment: Why does your server not already know the URL of your client? How is your client talking to your server to make the request if it is not your URL? Are you trying to farm for the URL of another iframe? it will help to know more about what exactly you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

No, that's not possible because PHP (server-side) is run before javascript (client side) code. You can do the opposite though. You will have to resort to one of these:

- AJAX
- Hidden Field
- Query String

Though, if you want to read the *current* page URL, you could use:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

Comment: JS server-side? *did you mean client-side?*

Comment: It is possible with AJAX, but +1 for your explaining

Comment: @Sarfraz thank you very much..but i don't know how to use ajax.

Comment: @masterio: Read the tutorial here: http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/ on how to implement it. BTW, jQuery's `ajax()` method can make it easy for you.

Comment: please what did you mean about "Hidden Field" ?

Comment: @masterio: `<input type="hidden">`

Comment: it's ok..but how i can use it with my case..sorry for my Qs

Answer (score 2):

To do what you're doing in PHP you could do `$url = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];`

Comment: I need this to break frames, block proxy websites and bots so $_SERVER not useful

Comment: Then it would help if you actually told us what you were trying to do, as most of the other responses are correct pointing out the difference between client and server side code.

Comment: What do you mean "break frames" and proxies?

Answer (score 1):

you might not be looking at this the right way. you can see the current path in the url by looking at this variable

```
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

[Read More](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

**Update:**

Since you want to prevent your site for being under an iframe, you can google frame busting script, it is done entirely in javascript.

Comment: I need this to break frames, block proxy websites and bots so $_SERVER not useful

Comment: The you should search for a frame busting script

Comment: almost of proxy sites can break it easy..i have tried it before..thank you for your help :)